# PHP + AJAX: How do I stop javascript from getting rid of operators when sending/storing data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to send back a string equation, for example "3+3", but when PHP receives it, it appears as "3 3" instead. Somewhere along the line, the operators are getting erased.

```
function sendEquation() {
    let str = document.querySelector(".equation").innerText;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        document.querySelector(".equation").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "Scripts/Maths.php?q=" + str, true);
    xhr.send();
  }
```

I think it might be getting lost in this code. If my assumption is right, how do I stop javascript from interpreting the value I want it to store and just send me the string as it's written?

Comment: You need to encode `+` or it'll be converted to an space: `xhr.open("GET", "Scripts/Maths.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(str), true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` means something in URL syntax, so you have to encode it:

```
xhr.open("GET", "Scripts/Maths.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(str), true);
```

The `encodeURIComponent()` function will turn `+` into `%2B`. That *should* be properly decoded at the server.

(Specifically, `+` stands for a space character, as you've discovered.)

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed everything.